# Ember component model for form element

Tags: ember.js

I am creating ember components for simple form elements with validations and proper styling with bootstrap. I am aware of ember validation libraries but I am doing this to better understand ember components.

Here is the jsbin link for the app.

```
http://jsbin.com/natuq/12/edit?html,js,console,output
```

How come I don't see and values? Is the property naming wrong or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property you are trying to log in `App.AecFormComponent` is actually a property on the `App.AecInputComponent` instance. That is why you don't see the value being logged.

You can observe this by adding the following observer (no pun intended):

```
App.AecInputComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  logValueChange: function() {
    console.log(this.get('value'));
  }.observes('value'),
});
```

This is expected behavior because components create controller-like scope inside of their handlebars blocks. You could set up an Ember binding between the two properties to link them or [bind the property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html) of the input to `view.parentView.value` or something like that (though that's hacky).

Comment: Thanks Duncan, makes sense. How would I push and capture the value of this input element(s) inside the form component?

Comment: Well I wouldn't use a component for that but I understand this is a learning exercise so I would suggest a method like [Em.computed.alias, demonstrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470377/2124849) in melc's answer or `value=view.parentView.value` on the `{{input}}` helper.